# how do I upload my image from spring boot endpoint to react

Tags: java, reactjs, typescript, spring-boot, image

I return and image "image/png" from spring boot

the image doesn't show in react
it works with postman.

```java
@GetMapping("/get-image/{fileName}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getImage(@PathVariable("fileName")String fileName){
    byte[] imageData= imageService.downloadImage(fileName);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("image/png"))
            .body(imageData);
}
```

```js
public async getImage(jwt:string|String):Promise<ArrayBuffer> {
    const response = await axios.get( 'customer/get-image/man-icon.png', {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type":"image/png",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`}});
    const products = response.data;

    return products;
}
```

```js
customerService
  .getImage(jwt)
  .then((response) => {
    const blob = new Blob([response], { type: "image/png" });
    setURL(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

```js
{url ? <img src={url} alt="Image" /> : <p>Loading...</p>}
```

The image doesn't show
[image]